# How to circumvent invariance? E.g. passing Array[T] to func(Array[U]) where T<:U

Tags: scala, variance

I'm practicing scala using an existing java library. It's quite common to pass **Array[T]** to **func(Array[U])** where **T<:U**. For example:

Java:

```
public class Quick { ...
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) { ... }
}

public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> { ... }

public class EdgeWeightedGraph { ...
    public Iterable<Edge> edges() { ... }
}
```

Scala:

```
class Kruskal(private val G: EdgeWeightedGraph) {
    init()
    private def init() = {
        val es = G.edges().asScala.toArray
        /* **Error** Type mismatch, 
         *           expected: Array[Comparable[_]], 
         *           actual: Array[Edge]
         */
        Quick.sort(es)  
        ...
    }
}
```

I believe it's because the fact that **Array** is invariant. Here's my attempt to circumvent this, but it looks ugly and inefficient:

```
val es = G.edges().asScala.map(_.asInstanceOf[Comparable[_]]).toArray)
Quick.sort(es)
```

How do I do it in a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are invariant because they are mutable. If they weren't invariant you could do something like

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit

val apples:Array[Apple] =  Array(new Apple())
val fruits:Array[Fruit] = apples
fruits.update(0,new Orange)

val apple:Apple = apples(0) //<= epic fail I now have an orange as an apple ?
```

The only way I can think of is to *copy* the collection to an equivalent immutable collection (subtype of collection.immutable.Seq)

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit

val apples:Array[Apple] =  Array(new Apple())
val fruits:collection.immutable.Seq[Fruit]=apples.toList // or apples.toIndexedSeq
```

then get an immutable collection and you can get variance

in your specific example you could change

```
val es = G.edges().asScala.toArray
```

to

```
val es = G.edges().asScala.toIndexedSeq
```

but then you will have to make the QuickSort signature accept an IndexedSeq I guess. It is hard to tell the consequences without more code ...

Comment: Vote up for the tip of immutability. But it isn't feasible in the situation where the library signature is fixed and that is often the case.

Comment: I guess you can't change Quick.sort signature and that the implementation is in place.Without knowing which parts are your code, which parts are libraries and which libraries it is difficult to be more helful ...